# Terminal not open after uninstall zsh ubuntu 20?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, zsh

**Problem**

After uninstalling **zsh** terminal could not open

**Tried**

Xterm and other terminals not open

When I login yyt2 console (alt + f1) it still asked the username and password again and again

When I open the .bashrc file in the first line I can see.

```
exec /bin/zsh --login
```

How I can remove this? Because zsh not exist any more

Any other possible solution?

Comment: Is zsh your default shell? Try using some kind of launch bar that your Window Manager provides and run `xterm /bin/sh` to start `/bin/sh` shell which should be present.

Comment: zsh is not my default shell, when I login with root user then zsh started

Comment: I open the file with text editor, it's a read-only file that's why I can't remove it

Comment: Why I cannot login in (alt + f1) screen?

Comment: The solution is I entered in GRUB mode whatever name it is then change .bashrc access after this I remove this line **exec /bin/zsh --login** and terminal works perfectly